# can you skip a row in Pentaho Kettle's User Defined Java Class

Tags: pentaho, kettle

Inside of processRow(), can you skip a row and not send it to the next step and just pull the next row?
I know the Filter Rows step after the UDJC is an option, but was just wondering if it could be done inside the UDJC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're implementing some logic in User Defined Java Class element using processRow() function, and you don't want to pass some rows any further based on some criteria - you can just skip the call of putRow() function for such rows.